# Misunderstanding arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Still learning JS, I have a new problem I don't understand.
I have an array containing two arrays. I would like to concatenate all the values from the first one. What I don't understand is when I type :

```
var test1 = [2, "wine", "ok"];
var test2 = ["Ok", "hello"];
var arrayArrays = [test1, test2];

alert(arrayArrays[0, 1]);
```

I get :

```
Ok,hello
```

(in an alert).

What I don't understand is what does 0 and 1 stands for ?

I understand that if I type

```
alert(arrayArrays[0][1]);
```

I get hello, but I don't understand what it means when I type [0,1].

It strange cause if I type :

```
alert(arraysArrays[2, 1]);
```

I still get 'Ok, hello'.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Bergi's link is spot-on, but a slightly more detailed explanation is that there is nothing going on with arrays there.  Inside the `[0, 1]` expression, the JS engine is simply reading `0, 1` using the comma operator, which essentially evaluates the operands and returns the last one, namely, `1`.  So `arrayArrays[0, 1]` is equivalent to `arrayArrays[1]`.